# I dont get style in mail content using PHP

Tags: php

I dont get style in mail content using PHP.My code is given belo.I got mail with out out style in content.I got only html view.I dont include the style completely in these page.how include style in mail content.Any body help.

```
 <?php
 // multiple recipients
 $to  = 'sender@gmail.com'; // note the comma

 // subject
 $subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

 // message
 $message = '
<html dir="ltr" lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<title>Zamisoft Invoice</title>
 <style type="text/css">
     #invoice {
  position: relative;
 padding: 18px;
 max-width: 840px;
margin: auto;
background: #f5f5f5;
border: 10px solid #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #888888;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #888888;
-o-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #888888;
box-shadow: 0 0 1px #888888;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 }


  </style>



<!-- give life to HTML5 objects in IE -->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
   <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"> 
  </script>  <![endif]-->

<!-- js HTML class -->
<script>(function(H)
 {H.className=H.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,"js")}) 
 (document.documentElement) </script>

</head>
<body>
 <!-- begin markup -->

<div id="invoice" class="paid">

   <header id="header">
    <div class="invoice-intro">
        <img src="logo.png">

    </div>

    <dl class="invoice-meta">
        <dt class="invoice-number">Customer Name</dt>
          <dd>6859</dd>
        <dt class="invoice-number">Reseller Name</dt>
        <dd>6859</dd>
        <dt class="invoice-number">Brand Name</dt>
        <dd>6859</dd>
        <dt class="invoice-number">Country</dt>
        <dd>6859</dd>
        <dt class="invoice-number">Group</dt>
         <dd>6859</dd>
        <dt class="invoice-number">Rate</dt>
        <dd>6859</dd>
    </dl>
 </header>
<!-- e: invoice header -->


<section id="parties">

<div class="invoice-pay">
            <h5 class="style1">Your Current Due</h5>
<br>

            <div class="box2">
        this cat is a hybrid of domestic and wild breeds :)
    </div>
    <div class="box3">
        this cat is a hybrid of domestic and wild breeds :)
    </div>
        </div>

  </section><!-- e: invoice partis -->

 <hr>
<section class="invoice-financials">

     <div class="invoice-items">
        <table width="637">
            <caption>
             Openning Balance<br>
            <br>
            from to
              </caption>
             <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="10%" style=" border-right:#003399 solid 1px;">
  Date</th>
                   <th width="32%" style="
   border-right:#003399 solid    1px;">Description</th>
                   <th width="24%" 
   style=" border-right:#003399 solid    1px;">Particulars</th>
                   <th width="14%" style=" border-right:#003399 solid 1px;">Credit</th>
                   <th width="10%" style=" border-right:#003399 solid 1px;">Sale</th>
                   <th width="10%" style=" border-right:#003399 
     solid 1px;">Price      (GPL)</th>
              </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th style=" border-right:#003399 solid 1px;">
    07-02-2014</th>
                     <th style=" border-right:#003399 solid 1px;">
     1000 aed 2-02-2014 3:45 pm </th>
                    <th style=" border-right:#003399 solid 1px;">
   iccic bank ernakulam mg</th>
                     <th style=" border-right:#003399 solid 1px;">credit</th>
                    <td style=" border-right:#003399 solid 1px;">10000</td>
                     $36,000</td>
          </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Romulan Troops</th>
                    <th>1</th>
                     <th>1</th>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>$7,650</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                     <th>Kestrel-class Shuttle</th>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <td>1</td>
                     <td>$10,220</td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Clocking Device</th>
                    < th>1</th>
                     <th>1</th>
                      <th>1</th>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>$50,000</td>
                  </tr>
            </tbody>
             <tfoot>
                <tr>
                      <td>Amounts in bars of Gold Pressed Latinum</td>
                     <td>&nbsp;</td>
                     <td>&nbsp;</td>
                     <td>&nbsp;</td>
                     <td>&nbsp;</td>
                     <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
              </tfoot>
         </table>
    </div><!-- e: invoice items -->


       <div class="invoice-totals">
        <table>
              <caption>Totals:</caption>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Subtotal:</th>
                    <td></td>
                      <td>$103,850</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <th>Tax:</th>
                    <td>5%</td>
                    <td>$5,192</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Total:</th>
                    <  td></td>
                    < td>$109,042</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
           </table>


     </div><!-- e: invoice totals -->


    <div class="invoice-notes">
        <h6>Notes &amp; Information:</h6>
         <p>This invoice contains a
   incomplete list of items destroyed by the Federation ship
   Enterprise on            Startdate     
   5401.6 in an unprovked attacked on a     peaceful &amp; 
    wholly scientific mission to Outpost 775.</p>
         <p>The Romulan people demand immediate compensation 
  for the loss of their Warbird, Shuttle, Cloaking Device, and
  to a lesser extent   thier troops.</p>
         <p>Failure to provide adequate compensation
  for the above losses will result in an immediate increase
  in Neutral Zone patrols &amp; a formal complaint will
  be filed in the form of increased aggresion on human 
  populated worlds within the neutral zone.</p>
     </div><!-- e: invoice-notes -->

  </section><!-- e: invoice financials -->


  <footer id="footer">
    <p>
         zamisoft</a>.
    </p>
   </footer>


  </div><!-- e: invoice -->


  </body>
  </html>
  ';

  // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

  // Additional headers
  $headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

  // Mail it
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  ?>
```

Comment: Please keep in mind, that E-Mail HTML is old-school style, dont use html5, use <font>-tags, write <p style="color:#333333"... and goole for supported tags and style by different major clients

Comment: You need to use inline CSS. Most Email services such as Google and Yahoo etc., will ignore `<style type="text/css">...</style>`

Answer (score 0):

Most of email clients do not support non-inline css. You have to add all css inline, also, not all properties are supported, [check here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). And images is not always shown for security reasons.